# Create a search in a range

Tags: python, arrays, search, for-loop, range

I am new to Python and would like a simple code to be executed however due to my understanding of the syntax I am not able to create it.
I would need to create a range between 1 to 10 and create an input function to search if this number is within this range. My code looks like this:

```
range=[1,10]
i=0
for i in len(range):
    if (i) > 1 and (i) < c:
        print ("HH")
```

However there is an error. Any solutions with explanations?

Answer (score 3):

`range` is a function so you can either use

```
if i in range(1,10):
```

or

```
if i >= 1 and i < 10:
```

In your code, you made a variable that happened to be named `range` but it was actually just a `list` with two `int` elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

The following might help you understand a bit better. First of all avoid calling your variable `range` as this is a Python function. It is used to return a list of numbers. It can take two parameters, a starting number, and an ending number. The ending number is not included in the list, so for 1 to 10 you need `range(1,11)`.

```
c = int(input("Enter search number: "))

for i in range(1, 11):
    if 1 < i < c:
        print(i, "HH")
    else:
        print(i)
```

This would display:

```
1
2 HH
3 HH
4 HH
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I am not sure which version of Python you are using. If it is earlier than Python 3, then remove the brackets from the `print` statements.

If you just want to see if the entered number is in a certain range, something like the following would be suitable:

```
c = int(input("Enter search number: "))

if 1 <= c <= 10:
    print("The number {} is in the range 1 to 10".format(c))
else:
    print("The number {} is not in range".format(c))
```

You would then see it display:

```
Enter search number: 5
The number 5 is in the range 1 to 10
```

Comment: Hey bro thanks alot i understand the syntax better.. However the output shows the looping .. is it possible to just print out 1 line to say if the number is range or not? the code below is the one i have generated.
c = int(input("Enter search number: "))

i=0
for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
    if 0 < c < 9:
        print("THe number is within range")
    else:
        print("the number is not in range")

Comment: I have added a non-loop version to just display one output. I have also shown how you can add the entered number into the text.